# Compact encoding of an elliptic curve point

Tags: elliptic-curves, encoding, quadratic-residuosity

I'm working on a project with elliptic curve cryptography (ECC), I'm using the secp256k1 library (the one that's used in bitcoin).

My goal is to create the most compact platform-independent representation of an elliptic curve point.

Currently my encoding consists of an `x`-coordinate, 256 bits wide, encoded in a big-endian form, plus the sign (oddity) bit for the y-coordinate. In order to reconstruct the point I use the curve equation to receive the value for the `y^2`, and then find the square root. Though calculating square root isn't trivial, this enables to pass only a single bit for `y`.

Now I'm thinking to get rid of this bit too. I realize that it's just 0.4% of the data, but for casual point (part of some bigger data set) it's usually aligned to the byte boundary, so it's practically around 3%. Anyway, I'd like to see if/how this is possible.

The idea is that for `y` there's a solution for (roughly) half values of `x`, so I thought about using this fact. So that if, for example, there's a solution for the encoded `x` then even `y` is selected. Otherwise there should be some transformation for `x`, and then odd `y` is selected.

Is there a way to quickly calculate the "counter-part" of `x`, i.e. some unique transformation from `x` which will give the quadratic residue for `y` to `x` which will not, and vice-versa?

Comment: Even if it is possible, the encoding must be non-trivial, which means a noticeable computational overhead when processing each point. Then the question is whether it is worth paying the price for saving just one bit.

Comment: Of course it depends on how non-trivial the computation is vs how critical the size is. And that' what I'm trying to find-out, how complex is it to find the counter-part of `x`.